# Access User Settings from Class in Sub Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a group of common classes in a sub assembly of my WPF app.  The common assembly is added as a reference to the project of my main application.  I want to know if it's possible to reference - from the classes in this sub assembly - the user settings stored in the Entry Assembly (my app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the settings into your sub assembly one way or the other. Your best bet is either a parametered constructor or a static class for this.

Comment: Yea, I currently pass them as a dictionary of strings with a static class to build the dictionary. I was hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: You can't access the main assembly from a referenced one without causing a circular reference.